# Is there a way to set only the background of block elements until only at end of text

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set only the background of block elements until only at end of text while keeping the css **`display: block`** property.

h1 and p are block elements when you set background to these block elements 
the surrounding element will look like a box.

see below:

[image]

If I set the css **`display: inline`** to these block elements the background is applied only on the text surrounding the element.

see below:

[image]

How do we apply the background only surrounding text like the one above but keeping the css property **`display: block`** to the element. Is there any hacks in **css** or **javascript** to produce same output above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an inline element inside the block element, like this:

```
<p><span>Text here...</span></p>
```

and style the inline element.

```
span {background: red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
strong {
background-color:#ffa500;

}
span{
background-color:#03a9f4;

}
```

```html
<h1><strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy</strong></h1>

<p><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy</span></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is new HTML5 tag available to mark/highlight any sentence irrespective of the element type(block or inline). But the downside is we cannot control the highlight color, its always in yellow

```
    <div>Lorem <mark>Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</mark> the industry's standard dummy </div>
```

preview at JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/gLbgukd9/#&togetherjs=xHVthKGqIE

I hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Oh yes...then I think this is the solution for question.... still wondering why ppl downvoted it...

Comment: Well, apart from the incorrect information, it adds nothing to the other solutions